Modification of subproblem objective function
I have the following decomposed compact model with the following master problem:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_t \sum_s \text{slack}_{ts} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \sum_r \text{motivation}_{its}^r \lambda_{ir} + \text{slack}_{ts} & = \text{demand}_{ts} &&\forall t,s &&\\
&&\sum_r \lambda_{ir} &= 1 &&\forall i &&\\
&&\lambda_{ir} &\in\mathbb{Z}^+ &&\forall i,r\\
&&\text{slack}_{ts} &\ge 0 &&\forall t,s
\end{align}
and subproblems($i$):
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &0-\sum_{t,s} \pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its} - \mu_i \\
&\text{subject to} &-M(1-x_{its}) \le \text{motivation}_{its} - \text{mood}_{it} &\le M(1-x_{its}) &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\le x_{its} && \forall t,s \\\
&&\alpha_{it} \sum_s x_{its} + \text{mood}_{it} &= 1 &&\forall t\\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\in[0,1] &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{mood}_{it} &\in[0,1] &&\forall t \\
&&x_{its}&\in \{0,1\} &&\forall t,s\\
\end{align}
Now i want to additionally impose the constraint:
$$\sum_i x_{its} \geq 1 \quad \forall t, s$$
My idea would be to add this constraint to the masterproblem, which yields the following constraint:
$$\sum_i \sum_r \lambda_r x_{its}^r \geq 1 \quad \forall t, s$$
How would i need to modify my subproblem objective function to additionally cope for this?

If $\gamma_{ts}$ is the dual variable associated with the new constraint, then the objective function of the subproblem $i$ becomes:
$$
\text{minimize} \quad -\sum_{t,s} \pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its} - \mu_i - \sum_{t,s} \gamma_{ts} x_{its}
$$

Your original problem is:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_t \sum_s \text{slack}_{ts} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \text{motivation}_{its} + \text{slack}_{ts} &= \text{demand}_{ts} &&\forall t,s \\
&&\sum_i x_{its} &\ge 1 &&\forall t,s \\
&&-M(1-x_{its}) \le \text{motivation}_{its} - \text{mood}_{it} &\le M(1-x_{its}) &&\forall i,t,s \\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\le x_{its} && \forall i,t,s \\
&&\alpha_{it} \sum_s x_{its} + \text{mood}_{it} &= 1 &&\forall i,t\\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\in[0,1] &&\forall i,t,s \\
&&\text{slack}_{ts} &\ge 0 &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{mood}_{it} &\in[0,1] &&\forall i,t \\
&&x_{its}&\in \{0,1\} &&\forall i,t,s\\
\end{align}
For the Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation, introduce $\lambda_{ir} \ge 0$ and substitute $\text{motivation}_{its} = \sum_r \text{motivation}_{its}^r \lambda_{ir}$ and $x_{its} = \sum_r x_{its}^r \lambda_{ir}$ in the (objective and) complicating constraints to obtain the master problem:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_t \sum_s \text{slack}_{ts} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \sum_r \text{motivation}_{its}^r \lambda_{ir} + \text{slack}_{ts} &= \text{demand}_{ts} &&\forall t,s &&\text(\text{$\pi_{ts}$ free})\\
&&\sum_i \sum_r x_{its}^r \lambda_{ir} &\ge 1 &&\forall t,s &&\text(\text{$\gamma_{ts} \ge 0$})\\
&&\sum_r \lambda_{ir} &= 1 &&\forall i &&\text(\text{$\mu_i$ free})\\
&&\lambda_{ir} &\in\mathbb{Z}^+ &&\forall i,r\\
&&\text{slack}_{ts} &\ge 0 &&\forall t,s
\end{align}
The reduced cost of $\lambda_{ir}$ is $0-\sum_{t,s} (\pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its}^r + \gamma_{ts} x_{its}^r) - \mu_i$,
so the subproblem for block $i$ is:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &0-\sum_{t,s} (\pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its} + \gamma_{ts} x_{its}) - \mu_i \\
&\text{subject to} &-M(1-x_{its}) \le \text{motivation}_{its} - \text{mood}_{it} &\le M(1-x_{its}) &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\le x_{its} && \forall t,s \\\
&&\alpha_{it} \sum_s x_{its} + \text{mood}_{it} &= 1 &&\forall t\\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\in[0,1] &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{mood}_{it} &\in[0,1] &&\forall t \\
&&x_{its}&\in \{0,1\} &&\forall t,s\\
\end{align}

Note that the symbol $\alpha$ is already used in OP's subproblem

@Kuifje Yes, corrected.

@RobPratt Thanks. Assuming now instead of $\sum_i x_{its}\geq 1~ \forall t, s$, i now want to enforce $\sum_i motivation_{its}\geq 0.5\cdot demand_{ts} \quad \forall t, s$. Do i again need to modify it to $\sum_i \sum_r \lambda_r motivation_{its}^r \geq 0.5\cdot Demand_{ts} \quad \forall t, s$ and add the new duals $\gamma$ or is it sufficient to just add the constraint without $\lambda$?

Yes, you need to do the substitution in terms of $\lambda$, just like in the first equality constraint.

@RobPratt. Thanks, and also add the duals to the subproblem?

Yes, you would also include the duals as coefficients of motivation in the subproblem objective. But a simpler approach is to omit the new master constraint (and its duals) and instead just impose an upper bound on the master-only slack variable: $\text{slack}{ts} \le 0.5\text{demand}{ts}$.

@nflgreaternba, I have a similar problem and I would like to know how do you try to initiate as well as add a new column to the coefficient matrix $x_{its}^r$?
